# Select Case Multiple conditions from 2 column, 1 being 3 different substrings

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have a multiple conditional need.From my research, a Select Case Statement seems to be the best idea. I'm still a rookie at coding macros. I think I'm lost on how it works.

'Chg' is the column where there 5 different possible conditions.
'Acro' is the substring in the product column that has 3 different substrings.
And depending on the those variables, I need to utilize different Vlookups. I did edit the code to remove anything that might be considered proprietary information.

I thought my 2 variables needed to be created... and this is where I'm currently stuck ("<<<<<<").
Here is the code:
'Note: Lastrow code is further up in the Macro. this is just a chuck that I need to fix/figure out.

```
Chg = Range("F8:F" & LastRow) '<<<<<<Stuck right here - no telling what else I've screwed up.
Acro = Range("I8:I" & LastRow)

Descriptions = Range("J8:J" & LastRow)

Select Case **Descriptions **'I'm lost on this. I can't tell if it should be an object that I Dim or Range.

Case InStr(2, Acro, "RRR", 1), Chg = "Removed"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "AAAA", 1), Chg = "Removed"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "RW", 1), Chg = "Removed"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"

Case InStr(2, Acro, "RRR", 1), Chg = "SS"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "AAAA", 1), Chg = "SS"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "RW", 1), Chg = "SS"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"

Case InStr(2, Acro, "RRR", 1), Chg = "Added item"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "AAAA", 1), Chg = "Added item"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "RW", 1), Chg = "Added item"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"

Case InStr(2, Acro, "RRR", 1), Chg = "RC"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "AAAA", 1), Chg = "RC"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "RW", 1), Chg = "RC"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"

Case InStr(2, Acro, "RRR", 1), Chg = ""
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "AAAA", 1), Chg = ""
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
Case InStr(2, Acro, "RW", 1), Chg = ""
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
End Select
```

What I have tried...

1. Dim'ing my 2 columns with conditions I need to use to get the code to use a vlookup to fill in descriptions from other files and/or sheets.
   Chg = Range("F8:F" & LastRow)
   Acro = Range("I8:I" & LastRow)
   I've tried both above and below, its still wrong.
   Chg = Range("F:F") '5 different text strings
   Acro = Range("I:I") '3 different substrings... acronyms
2. Select Case, Haven't gotten that far yet... but I mentally go back and fourth on whether it should be an object or Range.

And I haven't gotten far enough to to test further.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do in lamens terms... ?
If Fx = removed and Ix starts with RRR, go to this file and vlookup the descriptions on this tab.

This means there are 15 different matches that requires designation. I'm willing to try an if statement if its not too convoluted. Select Case seems like the better option... if I can get it working.

TYIA,Julie

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that I think will point you in the direction you are trying to go.

Note: If there is a relationship between the VLOOKUP formula and the values in columns F and/or I, we can probably simplify this further. Lmk.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Julie()
    ' Assumptions
    ' The Vlookup formula is supposed to go in Column J (Descriptions)

    Dim LastRow As Long, tmpRow As Long, strFormula As String

    LastRow = 100 'Change this to however you are determining last row

    For tmpRow = 8 To LastRow
        Select Case Cells(tmpRow, 6).Value
            Case "Removed"
                If Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RRR*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*AAAA*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RW*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                End If
            Case "SS"
                If Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RRR*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*AAAA*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RW*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                End If
            Case "Added Item"
                If Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RRR*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*AAAA*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RW*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                End If
            Case "RC"
                If Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RRR*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*AAAA*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RW*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                End If
            Case ""
                If Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RRR*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*AAAA*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                ElseIf Cells(tmpRow, 9).Value Like "*RW*" Then
                    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"
                End If
        End Select

        Cells(tmpRow, 10).FormulaR1C1 = strFormula
    Next tmpRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up not using this for the descriptions. However, I am trying to use this method for another section.

Comment: I got it to work for the other section - Thank you So much! huge help :)